# OsError [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema con una aplicación web que actualmente estoy desarrollando. La estaba desarrollando en otro equipo pero decidí terminar el desarrollo en un nuevo equipo y la aplicación funciona normal hasta que intento registrar una noticia en la base de datos, momento en el que me aparece error :

```
OSError at /add-noticia/
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
Request Method: POSTRequest URL: http://localhost:8000/add-noticia/
Django Version: 1.5.3
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:
[Errno 22] Invalid argument
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py in _save, line 198
Python Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.13
Python Path:
['E:\web_jfk',
'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip',
'C:\Python27\DLLs',
'C:\Python27\lib',
'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
'C:\Python27',
'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages']
Server time: Lun, 8 May 2017 20:13:06 -0500
```

Los campos que pide para el registro son nombre, titulo, autor y una imágen gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El error que da es que no encuetra un fichero. Con la información que aportas no es posible saber qué problemas tienes con la configuración, pero revisa qué cambia entre las dos instalaciones.

Comment: Hola, antes estaba desarollando en windows 10 y ahora es en windows 7 ¿eso tiene alguna diferencia?.

Comment: Agrega el `views` en donde tienes `add-noticia`

Comment: Tiene mucha pinta de falta de librerias. Comprueba que tienes todas las  INSTALLED_APPS que tienes en settings cargadas en el nuevo ordenador.